# How to check if itemscontrol item is in viewport

Tags: memory, optimization, windows-phone-8, viewport, itemscontrol

I am creating wp8 app and have a large dataset to represent through itemscontrol control. Problem is that I am losing to much memory because of the size of the elements. How can I check if itemscontrol item is in viewport?

Here is xaml I use:

```
                        <ItemsControl x:Name="showList" Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding tmp}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"></StackPanel>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,2,0,0" Background="#FF2E2E2E" Width="280">
                                        <Image Source="../Images/edge_shadow_x8.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="Fill" Width="8" Margin="0,0,2,0"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="time" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding StartTime}" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,0" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="show" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding title}" Width="160" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,10,5" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Can you use the LongListSelector control?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am trying to implement some kind of ui virtualization to reduce memory consumption and that is why I need to be able to access the single item and check if its in a viewport so I can manipulate that item. Thanks for commenting